# iframe into blogspot not working

Tags: iframe, blogger

I am trying to insert pdf into blogger using iframe.But I am getting blank page
Any idea How to fix it. I was getting blank page with chrome and firefox. I was getting error "This publisher does not allow to publish" in internet explorer

```
> <iframe width="100%" frameborder="0"
> src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B15mEFBok9BVUExXV2lRTDNsYjQ/view?usp=sharing"></iframe>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Google Drive has the HTTP header `X-Frame-Options` set to `SAMEORIGIN`. That means that it can only be embedded within the same domain (drive.google.com). You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

You should be able to see the error by opening your browser's console:

```
Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/file/u/2/d/0B15mEFBok9BVUExXV2lRTDNsYjQ/view?usp=sharing' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`
```

My recommendation is to host it somewhere else (e.g. Amazon S3), where you have control over the HTTP headers.